# Qt still calls .paint() on QGraphicsItem despite caching enabled and no calls to .update()

Tags: python, qt, graphics, qgraphicsview

I've been trying to draw many 'rects' efficiently in Qt (PySide), yet it still appears to lag drawing the entire 'grid' in the paint call of a QGraphicsItem.

```
class GridMapView(QObject, QGraphicsItem):

def __init__(self, gridMap, mapWidth, mapHeight, cellSize):
    QObject.__init__(self)
    QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)

    self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem.ItemCoordinateCache)

    self.gridMap = gridMap
    self.cellSize = cellSize

    self.width = mapWidth
    self.height = mapHeight

    self.setPos(-self.width/2, -self.height/2)

def boundingRect(self):
    return QRectF(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
    painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

    unknownBrush = QBrush(QColor('grey'))
    freeBrush = QBrush(QColor('white'))
    occupiedBrush = QBrush(QColor('black'))

    cellRect = QRectF()

    for ix, col in enumerate(self.gridMap):
        for iy, cell in enumerate(col):
            if cell == CellStates.UNKNOWN:
                painter.setBrush(unknownBrush)
            elif cell == CellStates.FREE:
                painter.setBrush(freeBrush)
            elif cell == CellStates.OCCUPIED:
                painter.setBrush(occupiedBrush)

            cellRect.setRect(ix*self.cellSize, iy*self.cellSize, self.cellSize, self.cellSize)
            painter.drawRect(cellRect)
```

This is rendering a few thousand rects, and lags a lot. Setting the cache mode (and making sure not to move the view) doesn't appear to help.

My assumption was that painting the entire grid in one pass would be efficient, if it only gets redrawn when one cell changes.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set `QGraphicsView.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)` on the view containing the scene with that item. In either case, when you pass (hover) your mouse accross a `GridMapView` item, its `paint()` is called, so all the squares are repainted in your case.

An alternative implementation would be to make each square an individual `QGraphicsItem` so that, provided above viewport update mode is set on the view, only those items are repainted that need be.